# Mail shows 2 unread but there are no emails

Tags: iphone, ios, bug, mobile-mail, hotmail

Recently my Mail app is giving me the 2 unread badge, but there are no mail messages in the inbox:

[image: 2 unread]
[image: pulled down to censor folders.]

I do not remember when this started. I am on 9.3 beta but it started on 9.2 before I upgraded (using OTA).

Also, the hotmail I use does not sync trashing so my hotmail inbox includes all emails that I have deleted from my inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Inbox, drag messages down slightly, Search field will appear. Start typing 'Unread' and filter will appear.
Use it. Probably it will help you locate those two unread messages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to “Settings”
Select “Mail, Contact, Calendars”
Select the mail account that shows the unread message.
Turn “Mail” to “Off”
Turn the iPhone / iPad off by holding down the power button for 5 seconds and slide to power off.
Wait for 30 seconds, turn the iPhone / iPad back on.
Go to “Settings”
Select “Mail, Contact, Calendars”
Select the respective Mail account
Turn “Mail” back to “On”

Answer (score -1):

settings-passwords & Accounts- select account that has the phantom emails - turn account off - re start phone - go back and turn account on again - messages should now be gone

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This is an answer to a 2 year-old question on a different version of iOS.  Is your answer accurate to that version or the most recent version?  Please state how your answer is better or different than the one already provided.